# Google Sheets script : Click on menu item

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to have a script that simply clicks on File > Download > PDF of a Google Sheets menu.

To simplify, I first tried to have the script click on "File".
With devtools I could determine that this menu item has *id="docs-file-menu"* so my function should look like :

```
document.getElementById('docs-file-menu').click();
```

But it doesn't work because *document* is not defined.
While searching for a solution, I understood that Apps scripts cannot interact with the browser, but I'm not quite sure whether that includes the sheets menus items as well?

Is there any way to make a script click on a menu item?
If not possible, is there any other way to make the "download as pdf" window appear?

Comment: Apps script is not the right way here. You should look into  client side browser addons(or Tampermonkey scripts).

Comment: Thank you. That's i thought and feared. Well, at least that will give me the opportunity to try and create my first chrome extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+file+as+pdf+google+apps+script